# Use another Activation Function in YOLOv7

Tags: yolo

How do you change the activation function in Yolov7? For example, the default activation function of yolov7 (except tiny) is SiLU according to YOLOv7 paper and I want to change to ReLU or other activation functions

I found a solution but it's for yolov5.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can go to models folder and change the activation layer from SiLU to ReLU against the layer you want to. See common.py & yolo.py to understand architecture & change activation function wherever required.